# Table of contents: Correct hyperllinks to two different "section 1"s

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, numbering

I have a document divided in parts, sections and subsections and each part starts with "section 1". I totally dislike this, but I cannot change that. So sadly, I have to cope with the arising problems: After setting back the counter, the hyperlinks in the table of contents are incorrect. Each "section 1" links to the first "first section" (that is, section 1 in part I). How to fix that?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\part{Part I}
\section{The First One}   

\setcounter{section}{0}
\part{Part II}
\section{The Second One}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this, that also happens to effect your choice of section numbering,  is to add the section counter to those that are reset by `\part`.  `hyperref` then automatically takes this into account when creating its anchors and links.  The basic command to this is

```
\@addtoreset{section}{part}
```

As this command contains the `@` character in its name, you need to wrap this in a `\makeatletter...\makeatother` pair.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{section}{part}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\part{Part I}
\section{The First One}   

\clearpage
\part{Part II}
\section{The Second One}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works fine, thanks. (And just to clarify: That is **not** my choice of section numbering. I more or less have to use this numbering mechanism.)

Comment: `\usepackage{chngcntr}\counterwithin*{section}{part}` is cleaner.